# What should be the minimum length of a salt and is it always unique with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Tags: php, database, salt

I'm working on storing the password of my users in my database in a secure way. I read a bit and I was recommanded to use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes to generate my salt. I do:

```
bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($thenumberIwanttouse, $cstrong));
```

It works, but I was wandering two things:

-What should be the lenght of my salt and in my database, if my salt have 30 character for exemple, I would just need a varchar field with a length of 30?

-Will openssl_random_pseudo_bytes  always generate a new salt?If not, should it mean that I need to compare my salt to all other existing salt in my database to make sure that there aren't any duplicate?

Comment: Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` they are the recommended method, and dont salt them they do it themselves. **Dont re-invent the wheel, especially in this area** hand cranked security is more likely to be wrong that better than a proper implementation. [See the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: if your'e generating random bytes, then DON'T use a varchar/text-type field. random bytes can/will randomly include what looks to be valid unicode character sequences, and varchar/text fields are subject to character set translation. this could mangle the salt's bytes by doing false character translations. use a blob/varbinary-type field instead.

Comment: What kind of field should I use then?

Comment: If the password_hash() salt themself, how do they remember the salt they used? Don't the salt needs to be in the database?

Comment: they are clever, you may have to do some reading to understand how they work. But basically people GENERALLY made such a HASH ( pun intended) of storeing passwords securely. The PHP community wrote these and got them properly tested

Comment: Remember, there was nothing wrong with the components of the Wireless router security mechanism WEP, it was just poorly implemented and not propery stress tested. So a useless security mechanism was born. Unless you are a security EXPERT, dont try and roll your own.

Comment: The salts are stored along with the hash which allows `password_verify()` to work. Have a look inside of the PHP [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw format length of the salt is 16 bytes and it is NOT hex-encoded. **However**, you are not supposed to generate it yourself, nor to have a separate field for salt in the database!

[password_hash()](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) will automatically generate a salt (and it will do that better than you could), and then store it *in the hash itself* - that's just how the algorithm works.

You shouldn't be using anything but `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` to make the whole thing work.

In addition, there are better alternatives to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` for generating random data, such as [random_bytes()](https://secure.php.net/random_bytes) under PHP7, or it's backport for older PHP versions - the [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) package.

Comment: The thing is, I was reading this: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#normalhashing. It semed to me that that personne really knew what I was doing, but is it that in php, all I need is really just password_hash() and password_verify()? Even when I was studying, I was told to store the salt in my database, but in this, paste the salt to a certain php function... How can I know who is actually wright?

Comment: **Did I not say this already in my comments** Nobody likes a comment snaffler!

Comment: You hadn't wrote your comment yet when I posted this.

Comment: @KévinDuguay Yes, under PHP, all you need is ``password_hash()`` and ``password_verify()``. The article you've linked to is indeed written by somebody who knows what they're doing, but it is not a tutorial on how to do password hashing under PHP.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You did say the most important thing in the comments section, indeed. But as you know ... comments are not answers. :)

Comment: @Narf Comment 21mins ago, your post 11mins ago basic maths

Comment: Then, I still have one last question, for the password_hash() what kind of field should I use in my database and his length. By the way, when I ask the length, I mean the number of characters it use. I say this because when you say 16 bytes for example, I know what a byte is, but it doesn't mean anything to me in this situation.

Comment: Use `text`. That way you'll always be prepared when PHP adds different hashing algorithms. This [tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) gives some insight.

Comment: When I use text, I don't need to specify a length, wright?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Your basic math doesn't include the time it takes me to actually write the answer, but that's not the point anyway - you know comments can't be marked as accepted answers, which is what other users would be looking at. Post your comment as an answer and I'll upvote it, if that's what you're unhappy about ... I wasn't trying to hijack a few rep points from you.

Comment: Whatever, it aint no biggie